# Is it possible to build a bootable CD Extra (i.e. 1 audio track & 1 bootable data track)?

Tags: boot, audio, compact-disc, bootable-media

More precisely, I was wondering if the standards for "CD Extra" and the El-Torito extension to ISO9660 are compatible and allow to create an enhanced CD with one audio track (readable on a CD player) and one bootable track (e.g. linux installation DVD)? Has anybody already tried doing this under linux?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible.

From [CD Mate Deluxe 2.2.4 (build 26) Released - Club MyCE](http://club.myce.com/f59/cd-mate-deluxe-2-2-4-build-26-released-45229/):

> [...] Bootable Data CD supported, even a bootable Mixed Mode CD [...]

I've found several claims that [K3b](http://www.k3b.org/) supports this too, but I haven't been able to verify it yet.